# Ruby on rails and crm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, crm, trx

I have CRM with apache, Redis and delayed job running and when I access a customer profile/dashboard it throws internal server error. Other that customer all others profile loads well. Looking into the server log I can find the below error. Can someone help me to fix it?

ruby 1.8.7

```
root@rails:/srv/www/crm/shared/log# tail -n 100 production.log


7:
8:         - if analysis.data_version > 2
9:           %tr
10:             %td{ :class => "icon #{analysis.kind}"} &nbsp;
11:             %td
app/views/customers/_current_analyses.haml:8:in `_run_haml_app47views47customers47_current_analyses46haml_locals_current_analyses_object'
/home/deploy/.bundler/crm/ruby/1.8/gems/will_paginate-2.3.15/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:168:in `method_missing'
activerecord (2.3.17) lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:392:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
activerecord (2.3.17) lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `each'
activerecord (2.3.17) lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `send'
activerecord (2.3.17) lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'
activerecord (2.3.17) lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:392:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
/home/deploy/.bundler/crm/ruby/1.8/gems/will_paginate-2.3.15/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:168:in `method_missing'
app/views/customers/_current_analyses.haml:6:in `_run_haml_app47views47customers47_current_analyses46haml_locals_current_analyses_object'
```

Comment: You need to provide more but, error seems to be occurred on line 8. Are you sure that you can call `#data_version` on `analysis`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, it appears that calling `analysis.data_version` is causing the error. Are you certain that `data_version` is a method or property of `analysis`?

Comment: Nelson... I'm not sure of the coding part... It works fine when I try to access dashboard of another client in the same CRM. I don't know why it occurs for this user alone